# Creating records by model

Tags: python, django, database

Suppose I have such models:

```
class Recipe (models.Model):
    par_recipe = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Line (models.Model):
    par_machine = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Measurements (models.Model):
    par_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    id_line = models.ForeignKey(Line)
    id_recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
```

Do I understand correctly that in this way I have a 1: 1 relationship, and adding entries ids will be automatically created `id_line,id_recipe`.

I will add for example:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
        recipe =Recipe()
        line = line()
        measurements = Measurements()

        recipe.par_recipe = row[1].value
        line.par_machine = row[2].value
        measurements.par_value = row[8].value
```

And the small question about measurements was conceived that all secondary keys should go to it, now it is implemented correctly?

Comment: No... The foreign keys will *not* automatically be set, you need to do that manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite like that, you would have to tie them together:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    recipe =Recipe.objects.create(par_recipe=row[1].value)
    line = Line.objects.create(par_machine=row[2].value)
    measurements = Measurements.objects.create(
        par_value=row[8].value, 
        id_line=line, 
        id_recipe=recipe
    )
```

None of this is db optimized, you could use transactions to optimize the db writes.

You could make it faster if there are a lot of rows by using transactions:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
        recipe =Recipe.objects.create(par_recipe=row[1].value)
        line = Line.objects.create(par_machine=row[2].value)
        measurements = Measurements.objects.create(
            par_value=row[8].value, 
            id_line=line, 
            id_recipe=recipe
        )
```

This would create a transaction and write one instead of each time. But it will also fail the whole transaction on an error.

see [Django Database Transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly)

You could get more creative by counting the number of records and writing every 1000 records for example by:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    for idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1)):
        recipe =Recipe.objects.create(par_recipe=row[1].value)
        line = Line.objects.create(par_machine=row[2].value)
        measurements = Measurements.objects.create(
            par_value=row[8].value, 
            id_line=line, 
            id_recipe=recipe
        )
        # every 1000 records, commmit the transaction
        if idx % 1000 == 0:
           transaction.commit()
```

Comment: Incognos, Could you please help, I am new to django and python, the file is quite large and I would appreciate any optimization.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I understand correctly that in this way I have a 1: 1 relationship, and adding entries ids will be automatically created id_line,id_recipe.

The relations will *not* link to the previously constructed objects, that would also be quite unsafe since a small change to the code fragment, could result in a totally different way of linking elements together.

Furthermore a `ForeignKey` is a *many-to-one* relation: multiple `Measurements` objects can refer to the same `Recipe` object.

You need to do this manually, for example:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    recipe = Recipe.objects.create(par_recipe=row[1].value)
    line = Line.objects.create(par_machine=row[2].value)
    measurements = Measurements.objects.create(
        par_value=row[8].value,
        id_line=line,
        id_recipe=recipe
    )
```

Note that a `ForeignKey` refers to the objects, not to the primary key value, so you probably want  to rename your `ForeignKey`s. A model typically has a singular name, so `Measurement` instead of `Measurements`:

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    par_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, thanks, And you can not tell the optimization account of such a record in the database?And the small question about measurements was conceived that all secondary keys should go to it, now it is implemented correctly?

Comment: @LokenGarvel': given you use PostgreSQL, you can use [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), otherwise it might be better to first store the objects in memory (of `recipe`, `line`, etc.), and then perform `bulk_create`s, and link the objects together.